# Driver circuit for Figaro FECS sensor - specifically FECS44-100

Tags: gas-sensor, current-sensor

I need help designing a driver circuit for a Figaro ammonia sensor [FECS44-100](https://www.figaro.co.jp/en/product/docs/fecs44l_product%20infomation%28en%29_rev01.pdf)

I also have in my possession, the official evaluation module [EM-FECS(A)](https://www.figaro.co.jp/en/product/docs/em-fecs%28a%29_product%20infomation%28en%29_rev00.pdf)

The schematic for this (on page 2 of the link) seems to be an amplifier to convert the output from uA to a 0-5v output. However I would prefer to read the voltage into a precision ADC, something like [AD7791](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad7791.html). The datasheet specifies a 33 Ohm load resistor, so I assume this should be placed between 2 of the pins, giving a full scale output of 3.3 mV

The sensor itself has 3 pins labelled:

- Counter
- Working
- Reference

Is anyone able to shed some light the function of each of these pins?

Comment: on the Counter/working/reference nomenclature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_electrode

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I was able to find much more information now that I know its called a "3 electrode cell" 
specifically I found this application note from ST 
[link](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b7/3a/2b/63/6c/10/46/27/DM00093722.pdf/files/DM00093722.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00093722.pdf)